# Javascript Date (Year)

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- Hide from older browser
var x= new Date()
var y= x.getYear()
var m= x.getMonth()+1  // added +1 because javascript counts month from 0
var d= x.getDate()
var h= x.getHours()
var mi= x.getMinutes()
var s= x.getSeconds()
document.write("Today's date is: ")
document.write(m+'/'+d+'/'+y+'  '+h+'.'+mi+'.'+s)
//-->
</script>
```

E.g Today date is  10 - 10  - 2011 ( d-m-Y) format
When i tested in 
Firefox 6.02  and Chrome 14 .0385  and opera 10.53 safari 5 : Today's date is: 10/10/111  18.1.6
On internet explorer ie8  :Today's date is: 10/10/2011  18.3.47
** i testing other thing..  but don't know why year getting wrong output  except internet explorer.Or other browser had different implementation getting year. ??
** print screen of the browser available if required..
link image http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/javascriptdate.png/

Comment: Use the getFullYear() method instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `getYear` method returns the year minus 1900. Use `getFullYear`:

```
var y= x.getFullYear()
```

In some versions of Javascript the `getYear` method returns a two digit year for years in the 1900-1999 range, and a four digit year outside that range. This applies to Javascript 1.2 and earlier, and all versions of JScript (i.e. Internet Explorer).

This inconsistency means that you would have to analyse the result and change it depending on what the year reasonably could be. If you can't limit the possible rangle of years, it's impossible to tell if a result of 111 means 2011 or if it's actually year 111.

Reference:

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear

> "getYear is no longer used and has been replaced by the getFullYear
>   method."

http://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear